# Two dissimilar continued fractions that are equivalent $F(q)=G(q)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, continued-fractions, conjectures

Given the following two continued fractions,with $|q|\lt1$

$F(q)= \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{q}{1+\cfrac{q^2}{1+\cfrac{q^5}{1+\cfrac{q^8}{1+\cfrac{q^{12}}{1+\cfrac{q^{16}}{1+\cfrac{q^{24}}{1+\dots}}}}}}}}\tag1$

where the exponents are given by the Generating function

$f(z)=\frac{-2z^4-4z^3-3z^2-2z-1}{2z^2-1}$

and

$G(q)= 1-\cfrac{q}{1+\cfrac{q}{1-\cfrac{q}{1+\cfrac{q}{1-\cfrac{q^4}{1+\cfrac{q^{4}}{1-\cfrac{q^{4}}{1+\cfrac{q^{4}}{1-\dots}}}}}}}}\tag2$

in which case the exponents are given by the generating function

$g(z)=\frac{-2z^7-2z^6-2z^5-2z^4-z^3-z^2-z-1}{2z^4-1}$

and satisfy the recurrence relation $a(n+4)=2a(n)$

for $n\geq4$

> How do we prove that $F(q)=G(q)$?

Note:by comparing coefficients of each continued fraction,we observe that they are equal.

Curiously though,by plotting each generating function on the complex plane yields beautiful images([f(z)](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2z%5E4-4z%5E3-3z%5E2-2z-1%29%2F%282z%5E2-1%29) and [g(z)](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2z%5E7-2z%5E6-2z%5E5-2z%5E4-z%5E3-z%5E2-z-1%29%2F%282z%5E4-1%29)) of bugs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\quad T_0(x, q):=1/(1+q/(1+q^2/(1+q^5/x))),$ 
$\; T_1(x, q):=1+q^2/(1+q^3/x),$
$\; T_2(x, q):=1-q/(1+q/(1-q/(1+q/x))),\;$ and
$\; E(F, G, q):=F+q^4/(1-1/G).\;$
Then $E( T_1( -q^8/(1-1/y), q^4),\; T_2(y, q^4), q)=
E( -q^4/(1-1/y),y,q)=0$ for all $y\ne 0.\;$
If for all $n>1,\;$ $F_{n-1}(q):=T_1(F_n(q),q^{2^n}),
   \; G_{n-1}(q):=T_2(G_n(q),q^{2^n}),$
then $E(F_{n+1}(q), G_{n+1}(q), q^{2^n})=0.$
Now, if $F(q):=T_0(F_1(q), q),\; G(q):=T_2(G_1(q), q),\;$
then $T_0(-q^4/(1-1/y), q)=T_2(y,q), q)$ for all $y\ne 0$, and
if $y=G_1(q)$, then $F(q)=G(q)\;$ QED.

Please do **not** edit my continued fraction expressions. They are perfectly readable right now.

Comment: @ Somos:Sorry for editing ,just that it's a norm in math.stack exchange to use MathJax

Comment: @Nicco Yes, I do use MathJax but **not** for cfrac since it takes up too much space with no real benefit.

Comment: @ Somos:Yes that's true.I must say the proof is beautiful

Comment: @Nicco Thanks. it is an effective use of recursion and simple algebraic identities, my two favorite tools.